# Gorilla/mux middleware next.ServeHTTP panic

Tags: http, go, gorilla

I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around a custom handler using gorilla/mux. It's actually working as intended, but fails at the very last step of calling `next.ServeHTTP(r, w)`

I start an http server, and attach middleware:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func NewServer() (*Server, error) {
    s := &Server{
        // some struct ..
    }
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    // Route all requests to /api3
    r.PathPrefix("/api3")
    r.Methods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")

    // Attach middleware, log a thing for each request.
    r.Use(LoggingMiddleware)

    // .. Some user endpoints
    r.Handle("/users", api3.PostUser()).Methods(http.MethodPost)

    // Bind to a port and pass our router in
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
    if err != nil {
        // handle error.. 
    }
    return s, nil
}

func LoggingMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Println("LOGGING MIDDLEWARE")
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r) <-- panics every time
    })
}
```

What's strange is that the above will print `LOGGING MIDDLEWARE` but promptly panics thereafter, referring to the `next.ServeHTTP(w, r)` line.

This example is almost a 1:1 example of Gorilla/mux's [own middleware examples](https://github.com/gorilla/mux#middleware).

I've attempted to attach the middleware at the end of the of the function, before calling `http.ListenAndServe`, thinking order was an issue. It did not work: The same result appears

PostUser looks like:

```
func PostUser() http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var req AddUserRequest
        err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&req)
        if err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        err = userDb.Add()
        if err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        return
    })
}
```

I suspected the `PostUser()` endpoint might be the culprit. However, removing everything and having a basic endpoint still reproduces the error, example:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func NewServer() (*Server, error) {
    s := &Server{
        // some struct ..
    }
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    // Route all requests to /api3
    r.PathPrefix("/api3")
    r.Methods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")

    // Attach middleware, log a thing for each request.
    r.Use(LoggingMiddleware)

    // health endpoint
    r.HandleFunc("/health", api3.Health)    
    // Bind to a port and pass our router in
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
    if err != nil {
        // handle error.. 
    }
    return s, nil
}

// Health returns 200 OK if everything is normal
func Health(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    _, _ = fmt.Fprint(w, "OK")
}
```

The above results in the same. I.e:

```
curl http://localhost:8081/api3/health
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

With a stacktrace as such:

```
backend-api  | LOGGING MIDDLEWARE <nil>
backend-api  | 2022/02/15 15:55:22 http: panic serving 192.168.80.1:59370: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
backend-api  | goroutine 14 [running]:
backend-api  | net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc0001dc0a0)
backend-api  |  /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1805 +0x153
backend-api  | panic(0x8bb2e0, 0xc40c70)
backend-api  |  /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:971 +0x499
```

Comment: I changed it to `fmt.Println("LOGGING MIDDLEWARE:", next)`, the output is:

```LOGGING MIDDLEWARE <nil>
| 2022/02/15 14:16:47 http: panic serving 192.168.0.1:64958: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

Followed by a reference to that specific line of code.

Comment: I see. So what does that mean: I have a nil pointer in the `api3.PostUser()` function, then?

Comment: To test it, remove the "r.Use(LoggingMiddleware)" line, the panic should still occur. Then fix `api3.PostUser()`, and once it works WITHOUT the middleware it should also work with the middleware

Comment: I added a sample of PostUser. The endpoint works as intended if the middleware is commented out. Hmm.

Comment: I have just reproduced the issue removing _everything_ and only having an endpoint that only does: `w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
 _, _ = fmt.Fprint(w, "OK")`

Comment: I just edited in an example that's completely barebone. Still errors out.

Comment: @cbll you have to use a `Subrouter` or you have to chain all the method calls on the returned `*Route` value. Example with [subrouter](https://imgur.com/HRHs5JW), example with [route method chain](https://imgur.com/FnYDKw5).

Comment: @cbll `r.PathPrefix("/api3")` by itself creates a `*Route` with a `nil` handler. Same thing for your `r.Methods(...)` call. And then the `r.HandleFunc("/health", api3.Health)` registers a new `*Route`, one that's separate from the two created by the other method calls. And when you get a request the `*Routes` with the `nil` handlers are matched and then fed to the middleware, hence the panic. At least that's how it looks to me, I do not use gorilla/mux so I may not have it exactly correct.